# How to upload image with FilePond?

Tags: laravel, filepond

I have Laravel app so I need to upload image for category, I use the [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/) library

When I upload image in in front-end everything is fine with the library but when make `dd()`  for my request I got this array:

```
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "KyEk4ha6UbMSG0WfYjD84wcUZU188pv1OK5utwrt"
  "name" => "d"
  "category_news_id" => "6"
  "desc" => "f"
  "image" => null
]
```

problem with image alway show null even I had uploaded image! e.g:

[image]

html code:

```
 <input type="file" name="image" class="my-pond">

$(function(){
    FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview);
    $('.my-pond').filepond();
});
```

Comment: Could you add the whole html form code ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI Done

Comment: Check if you may have forgotten to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI Already add it !

Comment: Set at least the following Filepond configuration:

FilePond.setOptions({
  server: {
    url: 'YOUR_SERVER_URL_GOES_HERE',
    process: '/process',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    }
  }
});

Comment: See https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/getting-started/#connecting-to-a-server

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI means this library just for Ajax request ? not for normal upload image

Comment: Yes, same like dropzone,...
You may consider looking at this package https://github.com/Sopamo/laravel-filepond

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI I got idea about the problem: the idea is: now when we upload image you can save just the name of image in session, then create delete fun for delete the last seessin name that had added when we want to delete it, and put the code of the store image in public file and db in store fun!
what do you think? :)

Comment: Yes sounds good to me

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI sir, could you help me with simple thing I got a great idea but I need some help if you have time pls.

Answer (score 1):

Blade File

```
<label>Upload Image:</label> 
<input type="file" class="filepond" name="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif"/>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.js"></script>
     <!-- include FilePond plugins -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.js"></script>
        <!-- include FilePond jQuery adapter -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery-filepond/filepond.jquery.js"></script>
          <script>
          FilePond.registerPlugin();
          var element = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
          var csrf = element && element.getAttribute("content");
          FilePond.setOptions({
            server: {
                  url: "{{ url('upload')}}",
                  process: {
                      headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf 
                      },
                  }
              }
          });
          const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[name="image"]');
          const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement);
          </script>
```

Route File:

```
Route::post('upload', 'AccountController@imageup')->name('upload');
```

Controller Logic:

```
public function imageup(Request $request) {
        if($request->hasFile('image')) 
        {  
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . date('mdYHis') . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
            $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/profile-image/', $fileNameToStore);
            return $data['image'] = $fileNameToStore;
        }
    }
```

Inserting the filename into database:

```
$user->image = $request->get('image');
$user->save();
```

Comment: cool but have you seen the delete button when I upload an image ? I need to create delete fun for it ? could you pls help with that>?

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding this would do the trick

```
FilePond.setOptions({
  storeAsFile: true
});
```